# Why can't I install the fglrx drivers for a RV620 card?

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx, catalyst

I have done everything correctly from: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775)

And after installation i use command:

```
gilu@gilu-desktop:~/catalyst$ sudo aticonfig --intial -f
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

What is not true because [wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware)  says that:

> - RV620       Radeon HD 3450/3470, M82

is spported.

```
gilu@gilu-desktop:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 LE AGP [Radeon HD 3450]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

**`You do not refer to the release version that you are using, assuming > 12.04 LTS`**

Your card is not supported by the latest releases of the ATI driver.

You will need to use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to install the legacy drivers or use the default already present and working, open source release of the driver. You cannot use fglrx drivers for our card on a Ubuntu release higher than 12.04 LTS.

[image]